# Is it possible to run Inifinispan continuous query with js-clien

Tags: node.js, infinispan

I am investigating Infinispan and its js-client. I have found Continuous query in the documentation but I can find an example of how to use it in node.js.

Does js-client support continuous query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Infinispan js-client does not yet support querying nor continuous query (we accept contributions ). You can still do queries over HTTP REST (see [example](https://github.com/infinispan-demos/infinispan-pokemon)), or you can go the C/C++ layer and do continuous query with that (see [here](http://infinispan.org/hotrod-clients/cpp/docs/8.3.1.Final/api_docs/html/index.html) and [here](http://infinispan.org/hotrod-clients/cpp/docs/8.3.1.Final/api_docs/html/index.html)).